# Is Renderscript incompatible with NDK libraries in the same project?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, renderscript

I have a problem creating an Android app that makes use of both Renderscript and native code generated with NDK.

Substantially, I use NDK tools to generate a library called `sprstr_native.so`. I managed to call their C++ functions through Java code without problems. Then I needed some Renderscript functionalities (in particular, `ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB`) so I've added to my Eclipse project a reference to the relative support library, `renderscript-v8.jar`, and this line in the project properties file:

```
renderscript.support.mode=true
```

Now the problem: Android can't recognize my `sprstr_native` anymore and the app crashes when calling the code:

```
System.loadLibrary("sprstr_native");
```

This is the stack:

```
11-23 17:46:54.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3901): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-23 17:46:54.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3901): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
11-23 17:46:54.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3901):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
11-23 17:46:54.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3901):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
11-23 17:46:54.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3901):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
11-23 17:46:54.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3901):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
11-23 17:46:54.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3901):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-23 17:46:54.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3901):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-23 17:46:54.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3901):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-23 17:46:54.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3901):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-23 17:46:54.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3901):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-23 17:46:54.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3901):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-23 17:46:54.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3901):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 17:46:54.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3901):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-23 17:46:54.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3901):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-23 17:46:54.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3901):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-23 17:46:54.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3901):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-23 17:46:54.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3901): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load sprstr_native: findLibrary returned null
11-23 17:46:54.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3901):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
11-23 17:46:54.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3901):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
11-23 17:46:54.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3901):     at com.lag.proj.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:18)
11-23 17:46:54.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3901):     ... 15 more
```

Curiously, **if I delete all the references to Renderscript the native lib turns to work again**!
Please don't tell me that there are incompatibilities between Renderscript and NDK code!

Comment: This proposed cause seems spurious.  Are you aware that `System.loadLibrary("sprstr_native");` will result in it looking for a `libsprstr_native.so` rather than a `sprstr_native.so` ??  If you list out the .apk contents with a zip file parser/viewer, what actual .so file(s) are contained within?

Comment: I can't check right now, but I can guarantee that the libray loading is right, simply because it worked before the Renderscript addition and returns to work if I "deactivate" Renderscript, as I wrote before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've probably solved it, but not without other errors that came after (see [Getting different errors for different platforms using Renderscript Support Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173680/getting-different-errors-for-different-platforms-using-renderscript-support-libr)). By the way, the library loading phase should be solved by adding this line on the `Application.mk` file:

```
APP_ABI := all
```

That lets the NDK to compile the objs for all the supported architectures.