# Renderscript causing library not to load

Tags: android, renderscript

I'm having a very strange problem. I am attempting to use the renderscript support library for Android. However, somehow it's causing one of my other libraries not to load and I get this in logcat:

```
12-18 19:50:30.031: W/System.err(16765): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load facialproc_jni from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.me.example.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.me.example, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
```

Then the app crashes...I can output more logcat if it helps.

I have no idea why this is happening...but it has something to do with my project.properties since adding these lines is the difference from it working and not working.

```
renderscript.target=18 
renderscript.support.mode=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out from [Is Renderscript incompatible with NDK libraries in the same project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165072/is-renderscript-incompatible-with-ndk-libraries-in-the-same-project?rq=1) that the problem probably had something to do with the two libraries being compiled with different architectures.

On a whim, I decided to try changing my armeabi folder holding the facialproc_jni.so to armeabi-v7a and it worked! Unfortunately, I don't particularly understand why it worked, if anyone has any insight on that. Maybe the facialproc_jni.so was compiled with both architectures and therefore can run as either?

Comment: I believe that the compatibility library only works with armeabi-v7a, x86, and mips. There is no support for earlier arm devices. Once you have a library in armeabi-v7a, that is the installation path for other native libraries, which leaves your armeabi-only stuff out.